# creating marker with xml file google map api v3 with geocodezip's downloadxml.js

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create markers with xml file and I couldn't find a solution
(loading xml, reading xml) I don't know where is the error.

Markers not showing up anywhere or a wrong place. I focus on  marker function to solve it marker function works fine. I don't get eror on chrome js console

**html** ;deneme1.co.nf/selcuk.html

**xml**  ;deneme1.co.nf/konya1.xml

example:`<marker lat="37.949615" long="32.496411" name="M1 Tepe AVM" cat="Alışveriş Merkezi" desc="M1 Tepe AVM</a><br><img src="resimler/real.jpg">" ico_wsize="20" ico_hsize="20" ico_wssize="20" ico_hssize="20" ico_icon="icons/supermarket.png"/>`

**js**   ;deneme1.co.nf/downloadxml.js

or http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/downloadxml.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>   
   <title>KONYA</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
var pnt= new Array();
var mrk=new Array();   
var bilgi=new Array();
var map = null;
var image=new Array();
var msg=new Array();
var name=new Array();

    function yukle() 
    {
    var mapOptions = 
     { 
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(37.95, 32.505),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);




downloadUrl("konya1.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        pnt[i]= new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("long")));
                image[i] = { 
                url: markers[i].getAttribute("ico_icon"),
                size: new google.maps.Size(markers[i].getAttribute("ico_wsize"), markers[i].getAttribute("ico_hsize")),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(12,16)
                 };
                   var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };

              //icon.iconSize = new GSize(markers[i].getAttribute("ico_wsize"), markers[i].getAttribute("ico_hsize"));
             // gölge ekleme  icon.shadowSize = new GSize(markers[i].getAttribute("ico_wssize"), markers[i].getAttribute("ico_hssize"));
              //icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(12, 16);
              //icon.image = markers[i].getAttribute("ico_icon");
              //icon.shadow = markers[i].getAttribute("ico_icon");
    var msg=markers[i].getAttribute("desc");
    bilgi[i]=markers[i].getAttribute("cat");


    name[i]=markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    mrk[i]=createMarker(pnt[i],name[i]);
    text2+="<option value=" + i +">" + markers[i].getAttribute("name") + "</option>";


        }
}




);
function createMarker(latlng, name) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
      titile: name
        });
}


createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(37.95, 32.505),"laps");      


}
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', yukle);
//ico_wsize="20" ico_hsize="20" ico_wssize="20" ico_hssize="20" ico_icon="icons/supermarket.png"/>

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: " i don't know where is eror" - neither do we.  What's the problem, are you getting an error downloading the XML file, is the map drawing but the markers aren't showing up, are they showing up but in the wrong place, or what?  You need to give us more information if you want anyone to help you

Comment: thank you for tips i add more information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is invalid:

http://deneme1.co.nf/konya1.xml

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 62: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
```

You have to encode the special characters, `<` should be `&lt;`

```
<markers>
<marker lat="37.949615" long="32.496411" name="M1 Tepe AVM" cat="Alışveriş Merkezi" desc="M1 Tepe AVM</a><br><img src="resimler/real.jpg">" ico_wsize="20" ico_hsize="20" ico_wssize="20" ico_hssize="20" ico_icon="icons/supermarket.png"/>
```

should be (at a minimum):

```
<markers>
<marker lat="37.949615" long="32.496411" name="M1 Tepe AVM" cat="Alışveriş Merkezi" desc="M1 Tepe AVM&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;img src="resimler/real.jpg"&gt;" ico_wsize="20" ico_hsize="20" ico_wssize="20" ico_hssize="20" ico_icon="icons/supermarket.png"/>
```

See Mike Williams' explanation in [this page of his Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic3.htm)

Comment: thank you for your answer however it was working on map api v2. i will edit xml  and write answers soon.

Comment: Did you change the XML?  Browsers don't handle invalid XML at all.  Please provide a link to a "working" v2 page that uses that same XML.

Comment: sorry for working xml file thing working in map api v2 i didnt get it from source i now check it after reading mike williams explanation.